# Firebug debugger not working in Firefox 3.x?

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox-addon, firefox-3

I have been using [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) for a while now and for the past month I can't get the JavaScript debugger to work. I mean, it will work sometimes, but it does random things 80% of the time. I don't think that it's just me because a friend of mine have the same problem.

I've googled the issue, and I can't manage to find an interesting answer. Same on http://getfirebug.com/.

Right now, I have the latest version of Firefox 3 on Windows XP and the latest of Firebug, but it has not been working since January.

Is there is a ticket opened or something? That would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using FF 3.0 then try removing the FireBug plugin and reinstalling it.  You may have to clear out the prefs.js file for all the FireBug settings.

If you are using FF 3.1 then there really isn't a good solution at this time, and if you need to use FireBug I recommend downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

usually when this happens to me i reinstall firebug.

also, firebug does not like LONG javascript files. if you can do something about the size of files you debug, try to debug a bunch of small files versus one giant file.